# H2: globally_quoted_identifiers seems not be taken into account

Tags: spring-boot, h2, liquibase

I use spring-boot 2.7.6 and H2 2.1.214.

To fix an issue due to the name of some columns that are also keywords in liquibase files (loaded to initialize the H2 database for tests) and entities, I tried to use the `globally_quoted_identifiers` property as defined here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_quoting_options

So I did it like this:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        globally_quoted_identifiers: true
```

But I still have the same errors due to keywords (`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException`) so I do not know if I use it correctly?

As a workaround I have to use `NON_KEYWORDS=VALUE,KEY` but I would like to manage all keywords globally.

Comment: Do you use a JPA Query or a native Query? Native queries MUST implement the quoting itself. JPA Queries will be translated by Hibernate.

Comment: The query in error was in a liquibase file so if I understand the `globally_quoted_identifiers` will not be taken into account because it is not a JPA query. If this is the case then I will keep the `NON_KEYWORDS` workaround.